# Javascript doesn't pass require statement in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I have Electron app and need to execute shell command. But when I call the gen_screenshot.js inside HTML, the execution stops at **const util = require('util');** line and the **document.getElementById('test_id').innerHTML = "Require passed!";** line is not executed.

When the script is executed in Node.js separately, it works fine.

```
// get_screenshot.js   
const util = require('util');
const childProcess = require('child_process');

document.getElementById('test_id').innerHTML = "Require passed!";

const exec = util.promisify(childProcess.exec);

const screenshot = () => {
    const { stdout, stderr } = exec('adb exec-out screencap -p');
    const screenshotData = stdout;
    displayScreenshot(screenshotData)
}

function displayScreenshot(screenshotData) {
    const imageData = `data:image/png;base64,${screenshotData}`;
    const imgElement = document.getElementById('screenshotImage');
    imgElement.src = imageData;
}

screenshot()

// index.html
<html>
     <head>
         <title>Display Screenshot</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <img id="screenshotImage" src="" alt="Screenshot">
         <h1 id="test_id">No</h1>
         <script src="get_screenshot.js" type="module"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...have you checked the devtools console and/or debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing relevant in the console.

Comment: So what happens when you set a breakpoint in the debugger on line 1 and do a step-through?

Comment: I run it in the debugger and saw 'require()' is not defined. So I insert webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false} when creating BrowserWindow and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I run it in the debugger and saw 'require()' is not defined. So I inserted

```
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
    }
});
```

and it works! The thread can be closed.

Comment: This config is **not recommended** for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security). You should use a [preload file](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) and [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).